# First term of an array not printing the correct value

Tags: c

I am trying to randomize multiple parts of a story in code. There are several parts that I will randomize, but whenever my random number is 0, the first items in each array do not print the correct value.

```
srand(time(NULL));

int random = rand() % 3;

const char *residence[2];
residence[0] = "house";
residence[1] = "apartment";
residence[2] = "trailer";

const char *color[2];
color[0] = "green";
color[1] = "purple";
color[2] = "red";

printf("%s", residence[0]);
```

I expected the output of printing the first item in the residence array to be house, but when I try residence[0] or my random number comes out to be 0, the output is red.

Comment: Your array is too small. Change `const char *residence[2]` to `const char *residence[3]` and same for `color`

Comment: Wow, I feel dumb. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

An array declared `[2]` can hold 2 elements, at position `[0]` and position `[1]`.

When you try to put something in position `[2]`, you are corrupting memory, and the results are undefined / unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution may be to have the compiler determine the size of the array based on the number of initializer present. eg:

```
const char *residence[] = {"house", "apartment", "trailer"};
const char *color[] = {"green", "purple", "red"};

srand(time(NULL));(

int random = rand() % (sizeof(residence) / sizeof(char *));

printf("%s", residence[0]);
```

The expression (sizeof(residence) / sizeof(char *)) automatically works out the modulus number based on the number of initializers in the array.
This way you can simply add more "items" into you array without having to be concerned about the [x] in the array declaration.